# Rule about Hands on bar during benchpress in Powerlifting competition?

Tags: rules, powerlifting

I need to find international rules on how arms should be located during benchpress in Powerlifting competition. So

**Which rules govern hands on bar during benchpress in Powerlifting competition?**

Answer (score 1):

[Technical rules](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/rules/technical-rules.html) govers the hands and the part 6 on [page 17](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/fileadmin/ipf/data/rules/technical-rules/english/IPF_Technical_Rules_Book_2016__1_.pdf) where I bold the key things

> *The spacing of the hands shall not exceed **81 cm measured between the forefingers (both forefingers must be within the 81 cm marks and the whole of the forefingers must be in contact with the 81 cm marks** if maximum grip is used). The use of the reverse grip is forbidden."*

where the most bars have marks that your hands must not reveal during the lift. Also notice the rule 2 with

> *His hands and fingers must grip the bar positioned in the rack
>   stands with a **thumbs around grip**.*

where any change in the elected lifting position would cause **Yellow card**. Powerlifting has three cards: red, blue and yellow that can be used to claim a failure, more [an page 8-9](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/fileadmin/ipf/data/rules/technical-rules/english/IPF_Technical_Rules_Book_2016__1_.pdf).

The rules governs the bar and knurling distances as well, more on page 5

> [image]

where notice the part 1 and 6. If you are looking for a bar, make sure that they comply with the rules -- recretional bars can fail in the weights, knurling and quality.